# Concatenation does not appear to be working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What am I doing wrong here?

I am trying to write a simple procedure to translate an encrypted string into a concatenated string of Unicode numbers. This will ultimately be a function that will receive the `@EncryptedString` as input.

When I execute this, the first print statement produces the seven-character string message for each character in the `@EncryptedString`, but the other two print statements only result in empty-string messages, not the concatenated `@UnicodeString`.

I realize this is written in a very procedural style, but its going to rarely be used and I'm a beginner at using a more batch-oriented approach.

Thanks for anyone's assistance.

```
declare @EncryptedString varchar(20)='†‚x†ˆ‹‡}‹ƒ†‚x†ˆ‹‡}‹ƒ'
declare @UnicodeString varchar(140)=''
declare @i int=0

while (@i < len(@EncryptedString)+1)
    begin
    print right('0000000'+convert(varchar(7),unicode(substring(@EncryptedString,@i,1))),7)--FOR TESTING
    set @UnicodeString=@UnicodeString+right('0000000'+convert(varchar(7),unicode(substring(@EncryptedString,@i,1))),7)
    print @UnicodeString--FOR TESTING
    set @i=@i+1
    end

print @UnicodeString--FOR TESTING
```

Comment: *"Just writing a simple procedure to translate an encrypted string into a catenated string of Unicode numbers"* Then why are you using a `varchar` and not an `nvarchar`? Why are you also using a `WHILE`? SQL is a set based language, it excels at set based operations and performs awfully as iterate ones (like a `WHILE`).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried it with nvarchar and it make no difference. I recognize that set based operations are more efficient than my procedural style, but that does not mean that this code should not work at all. This is something that is going to be run once every 90 days against a 20-character string, so efficiency is a low priority. The problem appears to be in the set @UnicodeString line in the WHILE loop, but I don't see what's wrong with that line. I've looked at dozens of like examples on this site, offered in solutions, that are almost identical, and all appear to work.

Comment: As for why it isn't working, you're expression, `SELECT right('0000000'+convert(varchar(7),unicode(substring(@EncryptedString,@i,1))),7)--FOR TESTING`, this first time it is run, returns `NULL`, `NULL + {any ltiteral string` = `NULL` and as you perform `set @UnicodeString=@UnicodeString` and `@UnicodeString` has the value of `NULL`, the value `NULL` is returned.

Comment: Insert `select @i, SQL_Variant_Property( @UnicodeString, 'BaseType' ); select @i, SQL_Variant_Property( right('0000000'+convert(varchar(20),unicode(substring(@EncryptedString,@i,1))),7), 'BaseType' );` before the `while`. When you add a string to a `null` the result is `null`. Not so with [`Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Or starting from the right index. (Oops. Typing while Larnu commented.)

Comment: `declare @UnicodeString varchar(140)=''` ?? That's most definitely not a Unicode string. The Unicode string type is `nvarchar`. Anything else uses a specific collation and will lose or mangle any characters from other collations.

Comment: @Ken what are you trying to do? Explain the problem, not the attempted solution. Your code doesn't use any Unicode strings. If you want to encrypt data, SQL Server includes encryption functions

Comment: @Ken this isn't a matter of efficiency, it's a matter of confusing code that simply won't work. Even the first assignment, `declare @EncryptedString varchar(20)='†‚x†ˆ‹‡}‹ƒ†‚x†ˆ‹‡}‹ƒ'` can mangle the text if those characters aren't valid in the server's collation.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to respond to some of these questions, but it seems you are only allowed one response per person responding to my question. The purpose of the code is to simply translate a string of characters ('†‚x†ˆ‹‡}‹ƒ†‚x†ˆ‹‡}‹ƒ') into a string of formatted ASCII codes. I, originally, erroneously thought I was in the Unicode world because of the bizare characters. I realize I was wrong. I've changed the code to replace the UNICODE function with the ASCII function, and the code still does not work.

Comment: @Larnu I gues the real question we need to ask is why OP thinks decryption (of a proper encryption algorithm) would be "a simple procedure" and whether it should even be attempted in T-SQL (rather than use one of the existing `DECRYPT` algorithms, or a CLR function)

Answer (score 3):

No idea what you're trying to do, but `nvarchar` is the unicode string type in SQL Server, and unicode literals start with `N`.  So at a minimum:

```
declare @EncryptedString nvarchar(20)= N'†‚x†ˆ‹‡}‹ƒ†‚x†ˆ‹‡}‹ƒ'
declare @UnicodeString nvarchar(140)= N''
declare @i int=0

while (@i < len(@EncryptedString)+1)
begin
    print right('0000000'+convert(nvarchar(7),unicode(substring(@EncryptedString,@i,1))),7)--FOR TESTING
    set @UnicodeString=concat(@UnicodeString,right('0000000'+convert(nvarchar(7),unicode(substring(@EncryptedString,@i,1))),7))
    print @UnicodeString--FOR TESTING
    set @i=@i+1
end

select @UnicodeString--FOR TESTING
```

Comment: U all are correct. I thought because of the bizzare characters, I was in the Unicode world. I now know I am not. Anyway, I modified the code as such, and it still does not work:

Comment: @Ken this page is Unicode. Windows, .NET, Java, JavaScript and now Python strings are Unicode. Unicode isn't some kind of escape sequence. As for your code not working, what is it supposed to do? It's quite likely that the text is already mangled due a conversion to ASCII. Or you're trying to handle binary data as if it was text

Comment: From [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15): "_start_ Is an integer or `bigint` expression that specifies where the returned characters start. (The numbering is 1 based, meaning that the first character in the expression is 1). If _start_ is less than 1, the returned expression will begin at the first character that is specified in _expression_. In this case, the number of characters that are returned is the largest value of either the sum of _start_ + _length_ - 1 or 0." `0 + 1 - 1`? ...

Comment: ... `select SQL_Variant_Property( Unicode( Substring( 'Foo', 0, 1 ) ), 'basetype' );` returns `NULL`. As does `select SQL_Variant_Property( Unicode( '' ), 'basetype' );`.

Answer (score 0):

HABO, your answer was the solution.

I don't know why, but I had defaulted @i=0 when it should have been 1. I looked at it 100 times and never saw what I had incorrectly entered.

That is all this was.

Thank you.